# Whitelisting domains in wagtail

Tags: wagtail

We're using wagtail with CSP (obviously) which means that every time we need to transclude/embed some content from another site we need to update a CSP whitelist as the only way to ensure that server headers play nice with embedded content.

Is there, however, a way to do this from within Wagtail itself, through its admin UI? This seems like the kind of thing a CMS-ORM should be pretty good at.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this isn't a feature of WagTail at the moment. It looks like there is an [open ticket on CSP issues](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/1288) (especially regarding Django CSP integration). It might be a good idea to add your complaint about the lack of UI to that ticket.

Since Wagtail is built on Django, I would suggest using the [Django CSP library](https://django-csp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) in the meantime, it seems fairly straightforward and is backed by Mozilla.

Comment: I'm one of the commenters on that issue already. We're currently using django CPS, and ii's an intractible a pain in the ass to have to constantly update a CSP config every time just because a content editor needs to embed something from yet another domain. It's great for static servers, but damn near useless for a CMS-ORM because it needs a good UI with policy base access to configure instead of having to edit environment variables/settings.py every single time.

Comment: That makes sense. Sorry I couldn't be more helpful, there aren't any plugins for it with Wagtail that I know of, so it would have to be custom work or added to the Wagtail repo. 

Have you tried to get their attention in slack or through these other methods? http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.4/support.html